# customer group_id changes on its own

Tags: magento

I have a magento 1.9 multi store setup with multiple customer groups.  Periodically - multiple times a day - a customer's group_id will change in the customer_entity table without any apparent cause.  this causes a number of problems because pricing is based on the customer's group.

Has anyone experienced spontaneous changing of the customer group_id?

Answer (score 0):

found the problem.  our client recently changed credit card processors to Squareup and we installed the Squareup Magento plugin so that they could accept payments.  the plugin installed a number of crons that did updates, including customer updates and because we are a multi store installation with multiple groups, it changed the groups to the default store.

Turning off the cron eliminated the issue.